# openinig two fancyboxes or Dialog with Iframe on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, dialog

So I have looked into this for ages. Got help with one issue but then another came up and I can't figure it out.

I need to be able to open a fancybox (or dialog with an iframe). Then within that fancybox open another fancybox (which I have working) and make that fancybox popout and be above the first one and movable. Then be able to open a second one next to that one. What I have now is I can open fancybox and then open another fancybox within that one. If I try to open a 2nd fancybox it closes the first one and opens another. I can't figure out why or how to fix it. I am willing to use Dialog with iframes to figure this out but i'm using inline c# and button calls for this.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
                fitToView: false,
                beforeShow: function () {
                    this.width = 1250;
                    this.height = 1200;
                }
            });
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href='website?id=<%#Eval("Key") %>'>
                                                    <center>
                                                        <img src="images/search.png" border="0" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" /></center>
                                                </a>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

this is to open the first fancybox.

this is within the second page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                fitToView: false,
                beforeShow: function () {
                    this.width = 1000;
                    this.height = 1200;
                },
                helpers: {
                    overlay: false
                },
                afterShow: function () {
                    $(".fancybox-wrap").easydrag();
                    $(".fancybox-wrap").append("<button id='handler' style='margin-top: -25px'>Drag me</button>");
                    $(".fancybox-wrap").setHandler('handler');
                }
            });
        });
```

Update:
I got it all working but now it's SUPER slow at louding. I Open up the first fancybox. Then within that fancybox I'm using buttons to open dialogs.They all open how I want so I can have 4 open if I need. Only problem I am having is since I added this it takes about 30-40 seconds to open up the fancybox. When I had fancybox open then open a fancybox inside and did same amount of data loading it went fast. But now this happened afert putting in dialogs. I have about 50+ buttons that are used to call dialogs. So I don't know if that will cause an issue. because with fancyboxes there was no issue. Any way of speeding up this issue?

Comment: Do you have some ajax refresh placed in loop?

Comment: No I don't. On the homepage I have a refresh but not within the fancybox. The loop is just c# inline using a for loop that grabs all the information and puts it on a table.